# back test issues on tradingview, is there a way to extend it?

Tags: pine-script

how to increase backtest period, as i am backtesing on 1-3 min time frame and tradingview keeps changing that, for example yday it was from 27 of sep to date, today its from 4th of oct to date and therefore changing my back test statstics, please share anyway you know of thanks alot in advanced!
note: i have paid subscription to extend candles on chart, but still i am facing problems on low timeframes

Answer (score 1):

I think you can extend it by a little bit if you use the bar replay function. Go as far back as possible with the bar replay, play it until the most recent time and then use the strategy tester.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response